# How to configure macvtap to let it pass multicast packet correctly?

Tags: linux, linux-kvm, centos-7, libvirt

I'm trying to create VMs which can see each other and host. They are hosted with qemu/kvm and managed via libvirt. The network adapter of VMs is created with macvtap(VEPA mode) for performance.

After enabling `hairpin` over switch, the unicast stream is all OK, no matter among VMs or between VM and Host.

When it comes to multicast, however, I'm faced with problem. I find that host cannot ping6 each VM. With tcpdump, I observe that the Neighbor Solicitation packet to multicast address `ff02::1:ff00:212` from host is not received by my VM, whose ipv6 address is `2001:da8:a0:600::212/64`. Obviously this multicast packet should have been passed to VM by macvtap.

As a result of the problem of multicast, all ipv6 packet is lost for Neighbor Discovery cannot work properly.

I'm sure that there is nothing with the switch, because when I run tcpdump over the physical network adapter, I can see Neighbor Solicitation twice per second, one out, one in.

After I set the macvtap interface over the host to promiscuous mode, the VM get the Neighbor Solicitation packet, along with some other multicast packet which should be filtered by macvtap, but no unicast packet to other VM, even when I ping6 other VMs on the host at the same time.

So I think enabling promiscuous mode over all macvtap interface is an acceptable workaround but not graceful.

All my host and VM is CentOS 7.0. I've tried to install kernel-ml(linux 4.1.3) from elrepo on my host but it make not difference.

So:

1. how can I set all macvtap interface to promiscuous mode everytime it's started by libvirt?
2. I'm not familiar with net driver. But according to http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-17-sect-14, I'm suspicious that there is some bugs in the driver of macvlan so that the kernel cannot set the multicast list of the interface correctly. However, there is no set_multicast_list in linux/driver/net/{macvlan.c,macvtap.c}. Where is the correct place to search for help?

See also: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1035253

Answer (score 11, accepted):

libvirt's macvlan has gained support for multicast.  Unfortunately it is disabled by the default setting `trustGuestRxFilters="no"`, and the documentation is not explicit that this breaks multicast.  As you observed, breaking multicast also breaks IPv6.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1035253#c15

You may be able to work around this by manually setting `trustGuestRxFilters="yes"`.  There is a limitation: "support depends on the guest network device model, as well as the type of connection on the host". "Currently it is only supported for the `virtio` device model, and for `macvtap` connections on the host".

https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICS

IMO the natural model would be to allow multicast by default.  Blocking multicast reception, on a network you think you're directly connected to, is an unpleasant surprise.  Especially since `macvtap` still seems to allow *sending* multicast packets (as well as spoofed MAC source addresses!).

Comment: I have just figured out this solution occasionally. Thanks very much. This feature requires additionally documented.

Comment: Thanks, that caused a lot of headaches. I think you're right it would be natural to configure IPv6 (intending it's use) and expecting things to simply work and _multicast_ is such an essential part of IPv6 that adding some confusing libvirt config kungfu to make it work isn't obvious and helpful here or at least giving a word of warning that you need promiscous mode on your macvtap interface would mitigate the unclear situation.

Comment: Maybe also worth highlighting here (although stated in the documentation) that `trustGuestRxFilters`currently only works with the `virtio` driver.

Comment: @ws6079 Thanks! I've added a direct link to the document, and highlighted this limitation.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by sourcejedi contains the solution, but maybe not explicitly enough. Using "virsh edit", set the `trustGuestRxFilters` attribute on the network device:

```
<interface type='direct' trustGuestRxFilters='yes'>
```

See [libvirt docs](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsNICS). The same can be done for [all interfaces on a libvirt network](https://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html).

Answer (score 1):

faced the same issue with macvtap. I found a way to fix it but I don't know how to automate it inside virsh.
sudo ip link set dev macvtap0 allmulticast on

Comment: It's more graceful than promisc, but this is still a workaround. The only way I could figure out to configure it automatically is crontab.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution although I'm not quite sure if it is completely correct.

Setup a [libvirt hook](https://www.libvirt.org/hooks.html) in which you enable ALLMULTI after the qemu domain is started.

**/etc/libvirt/hook/qemu**

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$2" == "started" ]; then
 timestamp=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
 exists=$(ifconfig | grep macvtap0 | wc -l)

 if [ "$exists" -gt "0" ]; then
   ifconfig macvtap0 allmulti
   echo "$timestamp ALLMULTI set on macvtap0" >> /var/log/libvirt_hook_qemu.log
 fi
fi
```

The script is working for me on Ubuntu 14.04.3 + KVM/libvirt.

Comment: this solution is not perfect for large amount of packets in ipv6 network.

Answer (score 0):

This is properly evil, but if you don't want to enable all multicast, this seems to work on the host:

```
bridge fdb add 33:33:ff:<lower 24 bits of v6 address> dev <macvtap if>
```

(enables reception of the just the solicited node multicast group for a particular v6 address)